# Why is jar file not being found with classpath spec? (FileChooserDemo from Oracle)

Tags: java, swing

Downloaded the latest Java SE. Ran FileChooserDemo via JNLP at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html 
Works fine. (Windows box.)

Downloaded the source from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#JWSFileChooserDemo

Following the compile instructions in the java source:

```
C:components> javac -classpath .;jars/jnlp.jar JWSFileChooserDemo.java
```

This works fine. Two class files are generated in the components dir. Then...

```
C:components>cd .. 
C:src> java -classpath .;jars/jnlp.jar components.JWSFileChooserDemo 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:javax/jnlp/UnavailableServiceException 
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) 
. 
. 
.
```

So the `UnavailableServiceException.class` isn't being found. But if you list the jar file, the class IS there. So my classpath is just wrong.

```
C:jars> tar tf jnlp.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
javax/jnlp/
javax/jnlp/BasicService.class
javax/jnlp/ClipboardService.class
javax/jnlp/DownloadService.class
javax/jnlp/DownloadServiceListener.class
javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.class
javax/jnlp/FileContents.class
javax/jnlp/FileOpenService.class
javax/jnlp/FileSaveService.class
javax/jnlp/JNLPRandomAccessFile.class
javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.class
javax/jnlp/PrintService.class
javax/jnlp/ServiceManager.class
javax/jnlp/ServiceManagerStub.class
javax/jnlp/UnavailableServiceException.class
```

I tried this on Mac OSX (you have to change semicolons into colons in the classpath) and same exact thing.

**Update:** I found an older version of this demo online that doesn't use `UnavailableSewrviceException` and compiles standalone.  It works fine with current Java and suits my purposes.  I still do not understand why the commands given above do not work.

Comment: You have to write `java -classpath .;jars/jnlp.jar JWSFileChooserDemo` from inside your `components dir`, not from one level up. Try by providing `Absolute path` for the `JAR` file as the `classpath` argument.

Comment: @nIcEcOw Then the `JWSFileChooserDemo` class is not even found.  It is in the `components` package, so I believe we have to run it from the dir above and specify the class as `components.JWSFileChooserDemo`.

Comment: The `Directory components` in question is created manually not by the compiler automatically. `-d` option of `javac` is used for this purpose, to create that heirarchy of `Directories` representing `package` automatically. Make a simple `HelloWorld` program with some package defined for it. And try to run that using `-d` option and without it. You will see exactly what I am saying :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps :

Say the directory structure is this on my side, under `C Drive` :

---

```
  components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject
                  |
  ------------------------------------
  |           |           |          |
nbproject    src      build.xml    manifest.mf
              |
          components
              |
  -------------------------------------------------
  |       |       |                               |
images   jars     |                               |
             JWSFileChooserDemo.java      JWSFileChooserDemo.jnlp
```

---

Under `components Directory` create a new `Directory` called `build` so now `Directory - components` will have five thingies, instead of four i.e. `build`, `images`, `jars`, `JWSFileChooserDemo.java` and `JWSFileChooserDemo.jnlp`.

Now first go to `components Directory`.

**To compile write this command :**

```
C:\components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject\src\components>javac -classpath images\*;jars\*;build -d build JWSFileChooserDemo.java
```

Here inside `-classpath` option, you are specifying that content of `Directories` `images`, `jars` and `build` is to be included while compiling `JWSFileChooserDemo.java`. `-d` option basically tells, as to where to place the `.class` files.

**Move to `"build"` folder :**

```
C:\components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject\src\components>cd build
```

**Run the Program :**

```
C:\components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject\src\components\build>java -cp .;..\images\*;..\jars\* components.JWSFileChooserDemo
```

Here inside `-cp` option `.` represents, that look from the current position, `..\images\*` means, go one level up inside `images Directory`, from the current location and get all its contents and the same goes for `..\jars\*` thingy too.

Now you will see it working, and giving the following output :

[image: JWSFILECHOOSERDEMOIMAGE]

---

### **EDIT 1 :**

Since you wanted to do it without `-d` option of the `Java Compiler - javac`. Considering the same directory structure, as before, move inside your `components Directory`.

**COMPILE with this command :**

```
C:\components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject\src\components>javac -classpath images\*;jars\* JWSFileChooserDemo.java
```

Now manually create the `package structure` in the `File System`, i.e. create `Directory components` and then move your `.class` files created previously, inside this newly created `components Directory`, and also add `images` folder to this newly created `components` folder.

Now `Directory - components` will have five thingies, instead of four i.e. `components(which further contains JWSFileChooserDemo.class , JWSFileChooserDemo$1.class and images folder)`, `images`, `jars`, `JWSFileChooserDemo.java` and `JWSFileChooserDemo.jnlp`.

**RUN the program with this command :**

```
C:\components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject\src\components>java -cp .;jars\* components.JWSFileChooserDemo
```

This will give you the previous output, though, if you wanted to move as suggested before, again copy `images` folder to the automatically generated `components` folder, since I just looked inside the `.java` and they using `relative path` for it to work.

---

### **JUST THIS PARTICULAR SOLUTION, I AM ABOUT TO DESCRIBE WILL WORK FOR YOUR CASE ONLY :**

If after `javac` command given before, if you don't wanted to create any folder, then go one level up, i.e. outside components directory and use this command to run the program

```
C:\components-JWSFileChooserDemoProject\src>java -cp .;components\jars\* components.JWSFileChooserDemo
```

If you don't wanted to

Comment: Thanks for putting in the time and effort here, but do you know what's wrong with my original approach?  According to my understanding of Java (which isn't great), it should have worked as I did it.  `-d` isn't mandatory right?

Comment: @Fixee : Previously, you compiled your `JWSFileChooserDemo.java` from inside the components. Now in the absence of `-d` option, when you will compile, then a new heirarchy of `package folders` will not be created. Do compile with `-d` and without it, and see what happens. In your case only `.class` files will be created, in my case the whole `package` heirarchy in the form of folders will be created automatically, and inside the respective folder, representing the `package` the `.class` file will be placed :-) Do ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, you are claiming the compile command given in the `JWSFileChooserDemo.java` file is incorrect then?  They give the command as I stated above.

Comment: No no, I am simply stating the difference between the two approaches. Though in your example, you are not suppose to move a level up, since what you created is inside the components folder, hence you have to run the `java` command fom there alone. Please do point me to the link, where they specified hO to run this...

Comment: So there **is** a java command that works without `-d` and a special `build` directory?  Can you tell me what it is?

Comment: @Fixee : Here do watch this latest last point, if you don't really wanted to create a new folder of any sorts, but this will work for only your case, since you already had a Directory with the name components, though it might won't be the case always.