# No Class Def Found Error (wrong name: components/FileChooserDemo)

Tags: java, swing, jar, applet, noclassdeffounderror

**C:/user/desktop> java -jar app.jar**
**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   FileChooserDemo (wrong name: components/FileChooserDemo)

**Demo code downloaded from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FileChooserDemoProject/src/components/FileChooserDemo.java)**

This file is used to create a jar application.

**manifest.mf**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_25 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: components.FileChooserDemo
```

Comment: Can you post your MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: yeah...sure just a second.

Comment: Change your manifest to `Main-Class: components.FileChooserDemo`

Comment: @c.s. I did and rebuilt, 
Error: Could not find or load main class components.FileChooserDemo

Comment: Is this class inside the jar? Please add details of your folder source structure, how you build and the resulting jar's contents (I also assume `FileChooserDemo` has a `main` method, right?)

Comment: @Nari2 : Please have a look at this answer regarding [JFileChooserDemo from Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17745494/1057230). Hope it helps :-) Moreover, it appears to me, that you forgot to provide a __newline__ at the end of the __manifest__ file.

Comment: @nIcEcOw new line is there.

Comment: @Nari2 : Have you tried the steps, posted in the link provided by me ? You can create a JAR file by following these [steps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15187181/1057230) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your class path is incorrect.  The class file is referenced and found in an incorrect location instead of components/FileChooserDemo as specified in the source.  Investigate your jar file.

Comment: I have everything in the same folder.