# When working with GUI's should I compile differently?

Tags: java, swing

This is code which I am copy-pasting from Core Java Volume 1 - Fundamentals. I just about understand the concepts and I like to see if it compiles. When I enter...

```
javac SimpleFrameTest.java
```

at the terminal it compiles fine. But when I type

```
java SimpleFrameTest
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SimpleFrameTest (wrong name: simpleFrame/SimpleFrameTest)
```

Here is the actual java code. Please let me know if I should be doing something differently.

```
package simpleFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleFrameTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                SimpleFrame frame = new SimpleFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class SimpleFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 30;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;

    public SimpleFrame()
    {
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: don't ignore the package structure.

Comment: I put all the SimpleFrameTest.java inside a folder called simpleFrame and compiled it from within there. Is this what you mean or did I do something else wrong?

Comment: Compile it and run it from the folder that holds the simpleFrame folder. Use voe's answer to help you compile and run it. Read up on using classpath too.

Comment: Please have a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17738100/1057230). Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry i have miss read the question, The reason why this

```
java SimpleFrameTest
```

is not working and throwing the following error

> wrong name: simpleFrame/SimpleFrameTest

is because as you can see your SimpleFrameTest is part of a some package, in this case "simpleFrame" Therefore in order to run this class you need to include the packagename in your command as well such as

```
java simpleFrame.SimpleFrameTest
```

A java package (simpleFrame) is a mechanism for organizing Java classes into namespaces